# Recommended way to store sql password on Azure iot edge

Tags: docker, azure-iot-edge

I am using Azure IoT Edge where I am using Azure SQL Edge module from the marketplace. I have another module written in Python which makes a connectivity with the SQL Server module on the IoT edge device. To make the connection, I have to hardcode the SQL password in the code.

I thought of storing SQL password on Azure KeyVault and pull it in Python module on edge while making SQL connectivity though this would defeat the purpose of edge. What if there is no internet connection for a while and my module will stop working.

Is there a safe way to store the SQL password on the IoT edge device or What is the recommended way to make the connection on edge? Please advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about Azure SQL Edge module. Just wanted to ask how is the device secured? Is it using the TPM, X.509 or Symmetric keys?

Also can you please let me know if the default password was already change to a strong password? Usually, when you change the default password for MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD to a strong password, it is more than enough as no one will have access to the device if it has been secured.

Refer to this document for more clarification -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql-edge/deploy-portal#connect-to-azure-sql-edge

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I am talking about Azure SQL Edge module. I have edited my query and mentioned it explcitly. Currently, I am using Symmetric Keys. The default password is changed though the problem is that when I write the code for my Python module which connects to Azure SQL edge module, I have to explicitly give the password in the python code. Other issue is that multiple people have access to the IoT edge device and I don't want anyone to find a way to know the password after getting logged into the Azure edge device.

Comment: I ended up implementing cryptography https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/
Keyring is the other option https://pypi.org/project/keyring/

Comment: Can you post the answer to your question TechTutorials? I am sure will help others better if it is as a verified answer ;)!